# How to pronounce "gemænscipe"?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, old-english, consonants

I'm not sure if Old English counts here, but I can't find the answer to this anywhere.

How would one pronounce *gemænscipe*? I believe it's Old English for "community".

Comment: The way it's spelled, of course. Old English spelling was rather good, and represented the sounds pretty well. In IPA, that would be, roughly, [yemænʃipe]. G before front vowels palatalized to [y] (IPA [j]), and SC before front vowels palatalized to [ʃ]. Why?

Comment: @JohnLawler I read it as `gem-ahn-sippy`. I doubt that's the way it's supposed to be pronounced. lol

Comment: But you're using Modern English spelling rules on Old English. You need Old English spelling rules, which are much more like European languages; pretend it's Swedish or Italian.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm sorry, that doesn't mean anything to me. :(

Comment: @mawburn: if somebody like John Lawler is telling you the correct answer, you should listen to him, not argue. If you can't read IPA,  *ge* is pronounced like the start of *yes*, *mæn* is pronounced like *man*, and *scipe* like *she pay*. I would guess the accent is on the *man*, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @PeterShor I was not arguing, I just don't know what he is telling me. Your answer is what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: It looked like you were arguing; sorry about that. Off-topic ... the word looks suspiciously like *yeomanship* to me, but aside from the *-scipe* part, I don't know if there's an etymological connection, and I can't find one in the online resources I briefly looked at.  (And certainly the meaning is different than any meaning that *yeomanship* might have in modern English).

Comment: No, it's quite different from _yeoman_ (which ultimately has the same root as _geography_ and _George_, I believe). It's an exact parallel with German _Gemeinschaft_, and has the same meaning.

Comment: I don't know the relevance, but it looks like another loan from old norse, which is now in swedish *gemenskap* and pronounced jɛˈmeːn.skɑːp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pronounce it as gə'mænʃipə. No one is absolutely sure about the pronunciation of Old English. Whether you pronounce g as /g/ or as /j/ is a problem as the change of /g/ to /j/ did not begin with a stroke of the bell in a certain year and in all regions at the same time. So it is a little bit up to you how you pronounce it.

Yes, gemænscipe is the Old English word for Latin communitate(m), nominative communitas meaning community. The Old English word has almost the same form as modern German Gemeinschaft. (I have to look up the word in Low German, it should almost be similar to the Old English form.)

Low German has a lot of slightly different regional variants. The most frequent form
is Gemeenschop.